# Replace string only inside of a link

Tags: php, string

I have a string like this:

```
<a href="blabla/test/city">city</a>
```

I want to delete only the last occurence of /city in the actual link and I will have this:

```
<a href="blabla/test">city</a>
```

I can’t just do a replace cause I don’t want to replace the city that shows in browser.

I’ve started doing something:

```
$x = '<a href="test/gothenburg">gothenburg</a>';    
$pos = strrpos($x, '">');
$x = substr($x, 0, $pos);                        
echo $x;
```

How do I achieve this replacement safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace`:

```
$searchText = '<a href="blabla/test/city">city</a>';

$result = preg_replace("/(\/\w+)(?=[\"])/u", "", $searchText);

print_r($result);
```

output:

```
<a href="blabla/test">city</a>
```

example:

http://regex101.com/r/gZ7aG9

To leave the `/` before the replaced word you can use pattern: `(\w+)(?=["])`

Comment: I do get the trailing slash at the end. I don't know why. I wasn't clear enough in my question. Is there a way of just replacing the LAST link in the string? (if there are more then one link in same string)

Answer (score 0):

```
strreplace(Href="blabla/test/city", href="blabla/test")
```

use the real str replace ofcourse

Comment: what the path doesn't contain "city", then you'll have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$x = '<a href="test/gothenburg">gothenburg</a>';  
$pattern = '/\w+">/'; 
$y = preg_replace($pattern, '">', $x);
echo $y;

?>
```

Comment: Explanation would be nice.

Comment: @Final Contest, Not really sure there is much of an explanation that can be given in that short code.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution using [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) that will look for the city name between the `<a href="…"></a>` tags, and then find the `href` and remove the last part of the URL that contains the city name:

```
// Set the city link HTML.
$city_link_html = '<a href="test/gothenburg/">gothenburg</a>';

// Run a regex to get the value between the link tags.
preg_match('/(?<=>).*?(?=<\/a>)/is', $city_link_html, $city_matches);

// Run the preg match all command with the regex pattern.
preg_match('/(?<=href=")[^\s"]+/is', $city_link_html, $city_url_matches);

// Set the new city URL by removing only the the matched city from the URL.
$new_city_url = preg_replace('#' . $city_matches[0] . '?/$#', '', $city_url_matches[0]);

// Replace the old city URL in the string with the new city URL.
$city_link_html = preg_replace('#' . $city_url_matches[0] . '#', $new_city_url, $city_link_html);

// Echo the results with 'htmlentities' so the results can be read in a browser.
echo htmlentities($city_link_html);
```

And the end result is:

```
<a href="test/">gothenburg</a>
```